# Python on Raspberry pi: no module named _bluetooth

Tags: python, bluetooth

I'm trying to scan bluetooth-beacons with my Raspberry in Python. The bluetooth dongle is working and i can detect the beacons with the command line.

But i want to discover them from Python. I've installed bluez and pybluez. From my python-script i run:

```
import bluetooth._bluetooth
```

I get the following error:

No module named bluetooth._bluetooth

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try 'import bluetooth' instead?

Comment: I don't want to sound cliché but have you tried rebooting your raspberry pi after installing bluez and pybluez?

Comment: how did you install  `pybluez`?

Answer (score 0):

Try `import bluetooth` or `import bluetooth.*`. It should fix your problem.